# Removing big files from the history/completely removing the history locally and then pushing it to origin

Tags: git, version-control

I am absolutely new to git and got completely lost. I am sure I miss something basic.

The problem is as follows:

1. I committed and pushed large files (~2Gb) to a repository. Then I removed them - committed - pushed, but they are still in the history. I need to shrink the repository somehow.
2. First, I followed [how to shrink a git repository](http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html). I could only shrink the local version, but when I tried to push, it said that I have to pull first. Pulling, however, would bring the big history files back.
3. Similar to [revert multiple git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/revert-multiple-git-commits), I removed completely the last two commits by doing twice

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD^
   git push -f origin master
   ```
4. Now, I can not see the last two commits in git log, but the repository/history is still big.
5. As the files are not in the history anymore, I can not [remove deleted files from git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676128/remove-deleted-files-from-git-history), as git does not see them.

Say, I am the only user of the repository and the history of no value, I just **need to shrink the repository somehow**. However, I **can only perform changes locally** and then push them to the repository, hence, [fully deleting the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init) will not work, as

```
    rm -rf .git
```

removes git and I won't be able to push.

How bad was doing 3? What can I do to achieve my overall goal? I would appreciate any suggestions. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: When you write "Then I removed them", do you mean with `git rm` or with plain `rm`?

Comment: The files were removed using ordinary rm, but they are still stored in the history files.

Comment: Hey Jubobs, actually, I did not solve the problem yet. I described the problem I still have in the comment to your answer below. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only if** (make sure you agree to each bullet point below)

- the history is of no value,
- nobody else than you depends on the remote repository,
- all the files you wish to keep in your working tree (but not necessarily in the repo) are currently in your working tree (and not buried in some commit),
- you want to start afresh with a brand new repo locally and then push that repo to remote,

do the following. Delete the `.git` folder in your project directory, then initialise Git again.

```
rm -rf .git
git init
```

Add your remote to the repo's config:

```
git remote add origin <url-of-remote-in-question>
```

Take a snapshot:

```
git add <at-your-discretion>
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Then force push your brand new `master` branch to the remote:

```
git push -f origin master
```

**Edit**: If that last force push command fails, it must mean that your remote repo is configured to deny non-fast-forward merges. See [Source Forge repo gives "denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450703/source-forge-repo-gives-denying-non-fast-forward-refs-heads-master-error)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Actually, it did not resolve my problem. In fact, when doing the last command (git push) I received the following error:

Comment: remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To <url-of-remote-in-question>
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '<url-of-remote-in-question>'

Comment: And when I tried to pull again afterwards, it pulled all my big files back. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're the only owner of the remote repo and don't need the remote `master` branch, try following the procedure outlined above but, before doing the final push, do a `git push -f origin :master` (note the `:`); that should delete the `master` branch that resides in the remote repo. Then, if everything is fine, try to push your local `master` branch to the remote: `git push origin master`. When you've done that, report here.

Comment: As I said, I am the only user of the remote repo and there is no need in the current history/master/other git files. I tried `git push -f origin :master` but I lead to the following error

Comment: remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable t
remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting th
remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master

Comment: Then I tried to change this configuration as described here [link](http://danielcsgomes.com/tutorials/how-to-allow-remove-master-branch-from-git/#.U_MBVLySy7M) but I could not ssh with -l root because of `Permission denied (publickey).` Without this option I could only change `sudo -u git_user git config --global` but not `sudo -u git_user git config --system` and as a result I got the error as before. Does it mean that I have some access rights restrictions? Can it be that my ssh key is not set properly?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I contacted my system administrator (the repo is a corporate one) and will come back to this post when I find out the problem (it can take several weeks though).

Answer (score 1):

@Jubobs Just to sum up, to make the solution above work I had to change some settings of the remote repo. In particular, I had to allow the following operation

```
git push -f origin master
```

by, first, ssh the remote repo and then setting there

```
git config receive.denyNonFastforwards true
```

In addition, to clim the space from the obsolete files on the remote repo, run

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=all
```

A natural question arises: isn't it easier to (1) ssh the remote repo, (2) remove .git folder, and (3) run git init to initialize a new repo. Well, it is also a solution.