# Discover and remove all deleted files from git history

Tags: git, github, git-filter

Here is the problem:

I have a github repo that was full of unwanted data and I decided to move them aside and leave there only my code there, as this is considered a best practice.

My problem was that it took too much time to clone or to change and commit a very small file.
Now that I have deleted all my data, I would like to erase them from the history of github, so that my repo becomes **small** again.

I've been trying various solution and none has worked.
My problem is that I really don't know what files I have removed, but I just know that I want to delete the history of **all files** that have been **deleted** from my repo until now.

Is there an easy way to do this? I guess it's a very basic and elementary problem, so a solution must exist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676128/remove-deleted-files-from-git-history) and also this [tutorials](https://silentinfotech.com/blog/remove-deleted-files-from-git-repository-history/) (just for deleting every file singles)